# Setting the right tone

Tags: applications

I am applying for a position in a maturating start-up IT company — 4 years old, about 10 employees — and want to find the right expression mode for my cover letter.

The job description is a bit informal, as it promises “a lot of fun” in the job. I would like to match this level of informality in my letter. Would it be appropriate to start with a “Hello Company!”?

My personal feeling is that this opening could be a little bit *too* informal, so I would be very happy to get suggestions for something between “Hello Company” and “Dear Sir or Madam”. A matching closings would also be very helpful.

Comment: http://workplace.stackexchange.com/q/33668/2322 ?

Comment: I don't use greetings in any emails including cover letters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't try so hard to find the right opening line. "To whom it may concern" should suffice. The expression is something you will have to create by way of paraphrasing in the body of the application.

You might consider using past experience, or hobbies, to moderate your formality.

Comment: I agree with Vietnhi and don't include a greeting. I certainly wouldn't use "To whom it may concern". The least you can do is try to find the name of someone at the company that you are trying to get in contact with. There's only 10 people, it couldn't be that hard to get a name.